# AppEngine Features and Tricks

Tags: python, google-app-engine

What are your favourite AppEngine features/tricks to make your development faster and easier? I don't expect one answer of course, but I would appreciate every AppEngine developer to have a share in this question. You can share anything including:

- Methods to make debugging easier.
- Methods for avoiding AppEngine data store limitations.
- Plugins to integrate with famous editors like Eclipse, Vim, etc.
- Methods for improving readability.
- Libraries to integrate with AppEngine.
- **Python features/tricks useful for AppEngine.**

Briefly, *share anything you believe made your development faster and easier, be it AppEngine trick or Python trick.*

Some people might argue that this question is not a real specific question. My argument for that is that we frequently don't know we have a problem before seeing the solution.

Comment: how is this more subjective and argumentative than all of the "hidden features of X" questions that are out there?  "hidden features of C#" is currently the highest voted C# question.

Comment: never mind, i see that the hidden features of C# was locked, despite being the highest voted question.

Comment: I don't really why they closed it actually. It also says "usually lead to confrontation and argument"! I can't really see a reason why having people sharing their opinions about AppEngine, a great tool for high-request rate servers nowadays, can be confronting! I wouldn't even agree about closing the C# question.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to Google App Engine **Tools and Tips** [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/tools_tips.html); it summarizes many useful tools and resources for working in App Engine

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems to contain many helpful information.

Answer (score 1):

I added [appengine_admin](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-admin/) which makes administrating entities easy.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the following things make my developement easier:

- Useing a freamewokr: [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) or [Tipfy](http://www.tipfy.org/)

  - If you plan to stick with GAE use tipfy as it is clean and simple
  - Other wise use django as it will be eisier for you to move to none GAE env.
- Useing [geaunit](http://code.google.com/p/gaeunit/) to unittest my code.